# Can I export from bigquery to a storage bucket that is accessed using different credentials?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been reading [BigQuery > Documentation > Exporting Table Data > Exporting table data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data) and now understand that I can export data from a bigquery table into a GCS storage bucket. The example Python code provided there demonstrates how to do this when the bigquery table and the storage bucket are accessed using the same credentials:

```py
destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, 'shakespeare.csv')
dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

extract_job = client.extract_table(
  table_ref,
  destination_uri,
  # Location must match that of the source table.
  location='US')  # API request
extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.
```

I am wondering if it is possible to accomplish this when the bigquery table and the storage bucket are accessed using *different* credentials. In my real-world situation what I want to do is export data from bigquery in projectA and store it in a bucket owned by projectB. Both projectA & projectB are accessed using different credentials. ProjectA is owned by a 3rd party and I have only been given access to bigquery, not to any of the storage buckets.

Is this possible, and if so, how? I suspect the answer is no, but just thought I would ask.

Comment: Can't you give the account that runs the query permission on the bucket? See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#permissions and the next section on Scopes.

Comment: Yes, long term we plan to do something like that however today I'm just trying to run an export and am having difficulty getting access to a person at the 3rd party that can grant the requisite permissions to my service account to access their bq dataset, so rather than twiddling my thumbs and waiting I thought I'd try and solve it a different way.

Comment: obviously, what you asking is not possible :o( - otherwise that would be such a security 'hole'. so you should get hold of that person

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that if you don’t have access to the 3rd party bucket. As [Mikhail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221944/mikhail-berlyant) has pointed out it would be a big security hole if you could upload to any bucket without permission.

For the time being you can extract queries and save them in your bucket, and once you have permissions you can transfer the files to the 3rd party bucket with either  [Cloud Storage API](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/index.html) or [gsutil command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp).